# Loading icon on state change with resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

I'm want to display a loading icon in my view, but I doesn't seem to work..

My view renders when my `$resource` in the `resolve` is loaded.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function () {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
        console.log('start');
        $rootScope.spinner = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        console.log('end');
        $rootScope.spinner = false;
    });
}])
```

Can't set the `spinner` because my view isn't loaded yet..

How am I supposed to `ng-show` on my spinner div then..?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the spinner to be outside of any view. That way you don't need to include it in any template but you'll still be able to control it with ng-show and watching state changes like you did.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by putting my loading div outside of the `ui-view`. 
Because it is outside the `controller` of the `ui-view`, I can just use the `$rootScope.loading` here.

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="loader">
    <p>Loading, please wait...</p>
</div>
<div ui-view ng-class="{transparent: loading}"></div>
```